# Is it possible to use the Android-framework in a Java-module?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-maven-plugin

I am new to Android development. I have the question if and how it is possible to use Android-framework code, like e.g. USBManager in a Java-module in Android-Studio. Or do I have to convert it to something else to do the trick?
Cheers
David

As I am currently not able to use imports like android.v7.etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in the android documentation. Java-modules are not meant to use the Android-framework. You must use an Android-library for that (There's also an option to create a Java Library, which builds a traditional JAR file. While a JAR file is useful for many projects— especially when you want to share code with other platforms—it does not allow you to include Android resources or manifest files, which is very useful for code reuse in Android projects. So this guide focuses on creating Android libraries. https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library)
Cheers
David

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use android specific code in java, when you create any new project using android studio, necessary files are made available to you.
To use any android specific library first you need to ensure whether it's 
directly available to you or you need any additional 3rd party library(that can be imported in app level build.gradle file).

Considering your example of USBManager (package : android.hardware.usb.UsbManager) write 'USBManager' and press Alt+Enter key, this will give you option to import the corresponding class from appropriate package.

If you still find any error, please comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it does not answer my question. I am currently writing a Java-Module and my question is if it’s possible to use the Android-Framework within it. For I have to change the build file, or convert it to an Android-Module?

Comment: I would suggest you to use  Android studio IDE for android development, its easy & it will create all the necessary build environment, import necessary files for you otherwise you'll have to follow lots of steps including- setting up gradle, sdk etc.

Comment: I am using the Android-Studio.

Answer (score 0):

David,

```
For android application development you can use following 
- Android SDK java classes
- Android NDK 
- Android support library
- native code as jni library(you can write your own native code or create wrapper over existing android framework library)
```